# How do I get the z rotation of my object as a public float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried different ways of getting the z rotation of my object as a public float but i keep getting errors when i make it a public variable.

i have tried using quanternion and transform.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PointerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;

    private void Update()
    {
        rotate();
        calculate();
    }

    private void rotate()
    {
        Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void calculate()
    {

    }
}
```

This part of the code is what i use to rotate my character to follow my mouse but i want to get a public variable saying the z rotation in the calculate method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PointerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float z_rotation; //THIS LINE

    private void Update()
    {
        rotate();
        calculate();
    }

    private void rotate()
    {
        Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        z_rotation = transform.rotation.z; //AND THIS ONE
    }

    public void calculate()
    {

    }
}
```

Another example:

```
  using UnityEngine;

    public class PointerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 5f;

        private void Update()
        {
            rotate();
            calculate(transform.rotation.z);
        }

        private void rotate()
        {
            Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        public void calculate(float z_rotation)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: how would i get this to show as a range from 180 to -180 accuratley as it is shown on the inspector

Comment: @theglozzom, try to use `transform.eulerAngles.z`, it returns value in 0-360 range

Comment: `z_rotation = transform.rotation.z; //AND THIS ONE` This wrong, it only returns the z component of the quaternion, which is not equivalent to a rotation around z. Like Nitro above me said, use `transform.eulerAngles.z` instead.

Comment: @yes , my answer, and my comment by the way :) I advised to use `z_rotation = transform.rotation.z;`, because Z component of the Quaternion actually SHOWING rotation, but it's in particular value. Because author of this question did not described that the required value should be in degrees, I gave an advice to use `transform.rotation.z;`. But then, in comments (after author's comment about how to get value in degrees) I described a variant with `transform.eulerAngles.z`. So, in my opinion the answer I've provided is completely valid.

Comment: yes a very particular value, which requires a calculation to retrieve the actual z rotation, no matter if radians or degrees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_Angles_Conversion